# Application of DOM locators in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I understood DOM locators but I don't know how to apply and locate the elements using DOM locators. I automate using Selenium with java but in DOM we have to locate writing `document.getElementById("id of the element")`. Copying same thing in Java code gives me error. Does any Library needs to be imported to use DOM locators or something else ?

Comment: You should spend some time reading some guides and tutorials. Your posted code is JavaScript not Java.

Comment: I know that is javascript. But then what is the use of DOM locators in Selenium ? How we use them in script ? When I read about locators, I came through DOM locators. In that, the examples were written like this. I didn't get how to apply that on my code. These are my doubts. Can I use them in Selenium with java ?

Comment: There is the code part that is javascript or Java or C#, etc. and a locator. As a Java example of the code part, you might have, `driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));`. The code part syntax will change between languages but the locator part will be universal. A CSS selector is a CSS selector in whatever language, e.g. Java would be, `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".someClass"));`, where python would be, `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".someClass");`. The CSS selector itself is the same but the code that accepts the locator as a parameter is different.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [document.getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) function inside your Java Selenium tests you can go for [JavaScriptExecutor.executeScript()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method like:

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id of the element');");
```

however much easier would be using [WebDriver.findElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)([By.Id)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the element"));
```

it is less code, more clear, faster and you will be able to use [Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) in case of testing [AJAX applications](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id of the element")));
```

Comment: Means using driver.executeScript(), we can locate elements using DOM locators. Right ?

Comment: WebElement element = (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id of the element');"); This didn't work.